# Flutter focus: is FocusNode the thing that has focus?

Tags: flutter, focus

In the focus system, there are a lot of widgets such as Focus, FocusNode, FocusScope, FocusScopeNode, etc. I'm trying to understand the focus system and have two specific questions:

1. Is a `FocusNode` the thing that is considered to be in focus? I know that FocusScopeNode has a `hasFocus` but it's not as if you can focus on a FocusScopeNode because you'd actually be focusing on it's FocusNode?
2. Is calling `.requestFocus()` or `.unfocus()` of a `FocusNode` the only way that focus will be removed or given to a `FocusNode`? (except for autofocus) In other words, things won't automatically be focused by clicking, tapping, or hitting `TAB` on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Flutter framework's focus system, a [FocusNode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html) is a representation of the focus state for a particular widget or group of widgets. When a FocusNode has focus, it means that it is currently the widget that is responding to keyboard events and other forms of input focus.

A [FocusScopeNode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusScopeNode-class.html) is a widget that is used to create a scope within the focus tree. A scope defines a new node in the focus tree, and all FocusNodes within that scope are descendants of that scope's node. A FocusScopeNode also has a `hasFocus` property, which indicates whether any of the FocusNodes within its scope currently has focus.

1. To answer your first question, a FocusNode is considered to be in
   focus when its `hasFocus` property is set to true. A FocusScopeNode is
   not something that can be focused on directly, but rather it is a
   way of organizing the focus tree and determining which nodes are
   within a particular scope.
2. To answer your second question, calling `requestFocus()` or `unfocus()`
   on a FocusNode is not the only way to remove or give focus to a
   FocusNode. In Flutter, focus can also be changed by clicking or
   tapping on a widget, or by using the TAB key to navigate through the
   focus tree. However, these methods of changing focus will only work
   if the FocusNode is part of the focus tree and is attached to a
   widget that is part of the widget hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for the response. To clarify on answer 1) As you say with `FocusScopeNode` having a `hasFocus` property "which indicates whether any of the FocusNodes within its scope currently has focus," is it true to say that in the Focus System, the thing that is *in focus*, or `hasPrimaryFocus`, will always be a `FocusNode` regardless of it's ancestors such as FocusScopeNode? That the deepest dependent in the focus tree, which has no further descendants, will always be a `FocusNode`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct! In the Flutter focus system, the object that has focus (i.e. the object with `hasPrimaryFocus` set to true) will always be a FocusNode. This is because FocusNode is the lowest-level class in the focus hierarchy, and is the only class that can actually have focus.

The FocusScopeNode class is just a container for other focus nodes. It does not itself have the ability to have focus, but it can be used to manage the focus of its child nodes. The hasFocus property of a FocusScopeNode simply indicates whether any of the FocusNodes within its scope currently has focus.

Comment: To summarize, the deepest dependent in the focus tree (i.e. the object that actually has focus) will always be a FocusNode, even if it is a child of a FocusScopeNode or other focus-related widget.

Comment: Got it! That will clear up some things for me. Thanks a lot!